# I wanted to search a word exactly and print line using python file handling

Tags: python

I have file that contains :

```
"1 2 3 4 5 5 6  searching new
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6  search"
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6  search and"
```

code:

```
with open('largeFile', 'r') as inF:
 for line in inF:
    if 'search' in line:
    # do_something
```

I am getting both the lines I want only second line.

Comment: I agree with the given answers: You have to be more specific. Python does what you tell it to do, so it checks the line for existance of "search". If you want to do it something else, you have to tell it to do so. I have problems expression yourself in python and need help, you have at least to tell us, what you really want to do. ;-)

Comment: You have problems expressing yourself in python;-)?

Comment: sorry, Now I have looked my original file so I have edited the above query

Comment: so you only want second line? then my answer if you want both then the other answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex.

Use **word boundary** (\b) to check for `words`, and `$` to check for **end of the line**..

```
>>> line = "abc search"
>>> if re.search('(\\b(search)\\b)$', line):
          print "true"


true

>>> line1 = "search asdf"
>>> if re.search('(\\b(search)\\b)$', line):
          print "true"
>>> else:
          print "false"

false
```

Comment: How to pass variable "line1" in if re.search('(\\b(search)\\b)$', line) in this code

Comment: You have that from the for loop:  -`for line in inF:` .. Use the `line` variable from it..

Answer (score 0):

Exclude `searching` like this:

```
with open('largeFile', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
         if not 'searching' in line:
             # do_something
```

Depends a little how the other lines look like. To be more exact you could do:

```
....if 'search' and not 'searching' in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if line.endswith("search")
```

But to be fair its not really clear what you want. please post more example lines and tell us which ones you expect.